# Collapse pandas data frame based on column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table below , I will like to group and concatenate into a new field based on the siteid using pandas/python

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>SiteID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Conserve</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Listed</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Listed</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

I will like the new table to look like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>SiteID</th>
    <th>Output</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>There are Conserve : 3, Listed : 5 </td>

  </tr>

 
  
    <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>There are Listed : 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

not sure what code to use, I have used group by. I tried this

`df = df.groupby("SiteID")["Name"].agg(";".join).reset_index()`

but I would like to put the result in a new field with a concatenate string as above

Comment: Can you provide your example as text, not HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (
 (df['Name']+': '+df['Count'].astype(str))
 .groupby(df['SiteID']).agg(', '.join)
 .reset_index(name='Output')
)
```

output:

```
  SiteID                  Output
0      A  Conserve: 3, Listed: 5
1      B               Listed: 5
```

If you need the leading "There are":

```
df['Output'] = 'There are ' + df['Output']
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine , I am trying to append it to a dictio nary, but the Output column comes through as a list instead of a string text

Comment: Not sure to understand, can you provide an example in your question?

Comment: I am appending it to a dictionary but it comes through like this {"attributes": {"Output": ["There are Conserve: 3, Listed: 5"], "SiteID":  "A"}} instead of a string text , not wrapped in a list

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve this:

```
res = (
    df
    .assign(Output=df[['Name', 'Count']]
            .astype(str)
            .apply(': '.join, axis=1)
           )
    .groupby('SiteID',as_index=False)['Output']
    .apply(lambda x: f"There are {', '.join(x)}")
)
print(res)
```

```
  SiteID                            Output
0      A  There are Conserve: 3, Listed: 5
1      B               There are Listed: 5
```